# EF Core 2.1 Code First, How to achieve automatic migration at runtime。。

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I want to automatically migrate changes when the program is running,so,the code written like this.
But except for the first time, no matter how the model is modified, the migration has no effect.

```
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                .CreateScope())
            {
                var database = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<StuDb>().Database;
                database.Migrate();
            }
```

So, I made a lot of other attempts, such as changing to this

```
    database.EnsureDeleted();
    database.EnsureCreated();
```

Delete  database.Migrate();   Add the two sentences above，This makes it possible to apply the latest model every time, but there is also a problem, that is, the data will be emptied every time. This is a big problem for development. I want the data to be retained to facilitate subsequent follow-up, such as functional testing.

Is there a way to migrate the database model to the latest entitymodel while retaining the data?

Please help me. Thank you!Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking is EF6 feature which has been "retired" in EF Core "by design", so there is no way to make it work. *Applying* migrations at runtime is supported via `Migrate` method, but you are required to use the design time tools to add *explicit* migration after modifying the model.

Comment: You should never apply migrations at runtime, unless you like broken applications. Migrating your database should be part of your release pipeline, and should be handled in a way that you can rollback and roll forward both the schema changes and the application code at the same time.

Comment: See issue [#6214](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6214)

Comment: I want to know how to the using C# code auto migrate the change, and do not use EF tool everytimes.

＃6214 Is too old,not support for new framework.Is there any new way to do it ?
Thanks!